# How to check if a column is not null based on another column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have 3 columns, Country, Period and Cost.

I would like to find out if the Country column is populated with a value, then check if the cost & period colunn are also populated with a value. if the cost & period colunn dont have a value, then bring back the rows where it failed.

so somethign like if country is not null then check if period or cost is also not null. if period or cost is null then return the rows that contains null.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well your question (if country is not null, then return the rows which have at least one of the Period or Cost columns null) you can use boolean indexing in Pandas :

```
df[~df['Country'].isna() & (df['Period'].isna() | df['Cost'].isna())]
```